# angular/typescript: ng-multiselect-dropdown mutliple properties in textField

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using the [ng-multiselect-dropdown](https://github.com/NileshPatel17/ng-multiselect-dropdown) package. I have successfully pulled my data into the dropdown, but I want to be able use multiple properties in the textField of the dropdown.

If I do

```
this.dropdownSettings = {
  singleSelection: false,
  idField: 'id',
  textField: 'nameFirst',
  selectAllText: 'Select All',
  unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
  itemsShowLimit: 3,
  allowSearchFilter: true
};
```

I get this result:

[image: dropdownWithFirstName]

---

I want to do something like this (nameFirst and nameLast in text field:

```
this.dropdownSettings = {
  singleSelection: false,
  idField: 'id',
  textField: 'nameFirst' + ' ' + 'nameLast',
  selectAllText: 'Select All',
  unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
  itemsShowLimit: 3,
  allowSearchFilter: true
};
```

When I do that, I get this:

[image: dropdownWithBadResult]

How can I go about combining the `nameFirst` and `nameLast` properties (with a space in  between)? Do I need to add another property to my user object? Can I do that on the fly or do I need to edit my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work around this issue by adding a `NameFull` calculated property to my `UserForDetailedDto` on the backend, accounting for the additional propety in my front-end model, and then using that for the `text-field` value.

#### Models\UserForDetailedDto.cs

```
public class UserForDetailedDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string NameFirst { get; set; }

    public string NameLast { get; set; }

    public string NameFull => NameFirst + " " + NameLast;

    ...
}
```

#### ClientApp\src\app_models\User.ts

```
export interface User {
  id?: number;
  username?: string;
  nameFirst?: string;
  nameLast?: string;
  nameFull?: string;
}
```

#### The dropdown settings

```
this.dropdownSettings = {
  singleSelection: false,
  idField: 'id',
  textField: 'nameFull',
  selectAllText: 'Select All',
  unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
  itemsShowLimit: 5,
  allowSearchFilter: true
};
```